# Retrain U2net Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data

I am trying to retrain u2net model. But there is no well written documentation on it. I want to train the model using 50,000 dataset.

```
epoch_num = 100000
batch_size_train = 2
batch_size_val = 1
train_num = 0
val_num = 0
```

I am not aware of these numbers; can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which realisation are you using but looks like names of the variables are pretty verbose:

1. epoch_num - number of training epochs or in other words how many times during training the dataset will be shown to the network
2. batch_size_train - number of samples in one batch during training step
3. batch_size_val - number of samples in one batch during validation step
4. train_num - number of samples in the training dataset
5. val_num  - number of samples in the validation dataset

If you are using official realisation of u2net training code than notice that `train_num` and `val_num` are set further in the code.

'epoch', 'batch', 'train' and 'val' are standard terms in the area of Machine Learning and if they are new for you you can easily find a lot of articles in the web that describes them in details.